# Create ramdisk on 16.04 for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to ask for help in order to create ramdisk for the cache of my chrome browser. I have an idea what to do but I do not want to crash my system therefore I would like to ask more experienced users. :)

So, what I would do:

1) Edit rc.local, then add the following:

```
mkdir /tmp/chrome
mount -t tmpfs -o size=4096M,mode=0744 tmpfs /tmp/chrome/
chmod 777 /tmp/chrome/ -R
```

2) Then:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome
ln -s /tmp/chrome/ ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

Is it the proper way to accomplish the task or are there simpler solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

1) Add a new entry to fstab, e.g.:

```
# TMP
none /tmp tmpfs nodev,nosuid,noatime,mode=1777,size=4096M    0    0
```

The **size** parameter can be different according to your needs.

2) Edit Google Chrode .desktop file, then add to the end of **Exec=** lines the following:

```
--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/chromecache
```

3) Save, then restart your browser.