# Increasing the Swap Space on Ubuntu

Tags: ram, swap

My Swap space is currently set to 2 GB.  How do I increase it?

Also I'm running with an SSD and have 16GB of RAM.  What is the Max Memory I can set the swap file to?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 has reached EOL on July 19,2018. Please upgrade to a supported version, eg. 18.04 for continuous support.

Comment: if you have 16 gigs of ram why would so much swap be needed? just curious :)

Comment: A lot of tabs open in Chrome... I'm constantly bouncing between different research topics ...

Comment: 1) This should be closed as duplicate 2) With 16 GB of RAM it's more than enough even for chrome.  3) Consider trying ramdisk for chrome instead  , see https://askubuntu.com/q/794290/295286

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK - That was a lot less scary than I thought it was going to be.  I increased the swap size to 8 GB with the following sequence (Based on the 3rd answer in the linked post - Note that I had to turn off swap first - If you look at your system monitor you will see Ubuntu emptying out your swap space as you run the first command):

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
sudo fallocate -l 8G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Verify it:

```
 sudo swapon --show
```

Make it permanent:

```
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

### Update

This worked great and my laptop stopped freezing due to memory hogging by Chrome.  One of the comments asserted that 16GB is enough, and in general I agree, but this is what my situation looks like:

[image]